# How to stop Rails process from accepting new requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

Suppose I have a bunch of Rails processes running with Thin and in front in is Nginx. My application uses WebSockets.

I would like to bring up new Thin instances with the Rails app upgraded. Tell my old Rails processes to stop accepting WebSocket connections (and as well as normal http requests) so that the new processes accept the WebSocket connections and http requests. Close the WebSocket connections on the old Rails processes to force clients to reconnect to the new processes. Then finally shutdown all the old instances.

Is this possible? I couldn't find an obvious way to do this looking at the documentation for Thin, Nginx, and Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing functionality that is built in to Unicorn, so Unicorn might be a better fit if this functionality is important to you.

There is a good write-up on Unicorn here: https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn

Comment: As far as I understand Unicorn isn't designed to be able to handle WebSockets.